# NSClassFromString not totally dynamic - Swift2

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

I've this sample code :

```
let structType: String = "elearning_lesson"
    if let classType = NSClassFromString(structType) as? elearning_lesson.Type {
        let object = classType.init()
        object.lesson_id = "15"
        object.test()
    }
```

Of course, structType value may be different, so i would like something like that

```
let structType: String = "elearning_lesson"
    if let classType = NSClassFromString(structType) as? structType.Type {
        let object = classType.init()
        object.lesson_id = "15"
        object.test()
    }
```

but i get error : 'structType' is not a type

How i can totally dynamize class instanciation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code I assume you want dynamically choose a class, and then call known methods. For that you will need to define a protocol first. For example:

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
    init()
    var lessonID: String { get set }
    func test()
}
```

Then you will need to create classes that conform to this protocol.

Once you've done that, you will be able to do this:

```
let className = "MyModule.MyClass" // this is how swift class names look like

if let classType = NSClassFromString(className) as? MyProtocol.Type {
    // call methods from your class, but only those specified in the protocol:
    let object = classType.init()
    object.lessonID = "15"
    object.test()
}
```

Comment: thanks, i just learn swift language, I did not know it was possible to do with protocols !

Comment: I should add that instead of a protocol you can also use a base class. That would be useful if all the subclasses should have some default behavior.

Comment: Might also add that there is no need for the string or the use of NSClassFromString. That seems to be a red herring...

Comment: Well yes, it is possible to use variables that store a class type, or even better, generics, but I don't know what OP is trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4):

> How i can totally dynamize class instanciation

In Swift, you can't. Swift is the opposite of totally dynamic. It is totally static! All declared types must be unambiguously known and specified at compile time.

(The fact that you are dipping into an Objective-C / Cocoa feature reachable from Swift doesn't change that.)

Comment: thanks for clarification, I do not know if I left on a good base, I was looking for an alternative if not, @Beirs give me a solution, thank you both